# How to filter shell result

Tags: ansible-playbook

We have run a playbook with shell module to retrieve data using curl command 
we are able retrieve data but that data containing lot of information so would like filter that data.

can some one tell me how can i filter those data ?

Comment: What format is the data, how would you like to filter it? Edit your question to add an example.

Answer (score 0):

This Stackoverflow answer seems to overlap well with your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45740777/ansible-parse-text-string-from-stdout